# How do I make an output stream do something later?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to make an output stream print something later on. I want to make it work like this:

```
cout << printThisLater("Hello, World") << x << y << printItNow();
```

I want the stream to remember the string that I pass to it. How can I do this?

This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string msg;

std::ostream& printThisLater(std::string str)
{
    msg = str;
    return // ??
}

std::string printItNow()
{
    return msg;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10, y = 59;

    std::cout << printThisLater("Hello World") << x << y << printItNow();
}
```

Comment: why not store your strings in a queue and dequeue when you want to print something. 
kind of a buffer

Comment: Create a stream object, that forwards all calls to an internal stringstream. Implement a marker object that causes your stream to write the internal stringstream to the actual output?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just attach the data you want to print later to the stream and retrieve it when needed. Here is how this could be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class print_this_later {
    std::string value;
public:
    print_this_later(std::string const& value): value(value) {}
    std::string const& str() const { return this->value; }
    static int index() {
        static int rc = std::ios_base::xalloc(); return rc;
    }
    static void erase(std::ios_base::event ev, std::ios_base& ios, int index) {
        if (ev == std::ios_base::erase_event) {
            delete static_cast<std::string*>(ios.pword(index));
        }
    }
};
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, print_this_later const& value) {
    void*& pword(out.pword(value.index()));
    if (pword) {
        std::unique_ptr<std::string> tmp(static_cast<std::string*>(pword));
        pword = 0;
        pword = new std::string(*tmp + value.str());
    }
    else {
        out.register_callback(&print_this_later::erase, value.index());
        pword = new std::string(value.str());
    }
    return out;
}

std::ostream& print_now(std::ostream& out) {
    return out << *static_cast<std::string*>(out.pword(print_this_later::index()));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << print_this_later("world")
              << print_this_later("!")
              << "hello" << ", " << print_now << '\n';
}
```

The basic idea is that `print_this_later(string)` is an object which stores `string` with a stream when it is "written" to a stream. The value is stored in a `pword()` entry: with

```
out.pword(index)
```

you get access to a `void*&` which is associated with `out` under the index `index`. Initially, the value will be null and it will retain the value it last acquired. Since there can only be a `void*` stored, the object is allocate on the heap and needs to be cleaned up. The clean-up can be done via a registered callback which is called when the stream is destroyed.

Comment: +1 What is your take on [Ch.36/38 of the Apache STL user guide](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/38-1.html), where they present both your approach of `pword/xalloc/register_callback` and an alternative, namely deriving from `std::basic_iostream` and using `dynamic_cast` and RTTI to add user-defined data to a stream? I've been struggling with user-defined manipulators for chess-like games where I want to be able to say `std::cout << algebraic << some_move;` that formats the *following* move in standard algebraic notation.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Clearly, deriving for all sorts of associated data doesn't work too well! If you just need one additional data item it sort of works but as soon as there are multiple values, as is like for, e.g., `std::cout`, it doesn't work. ... not to mention that you can't replace the type of `std::cout` in the first place. The constraint of _only_ having a pointer isn't much of an issue: just point to whatever is needed and I'd think the clean-up is part of the implementation! I think the documentation you quoted is ill-advised.

Comment: @TemplateRex: I'm not sure what you trouble was with your `algebraic` setting. Note, however, that generally formatting flags are _sticky_. The only exception in the standard C++ library is the `width()`. If you want to have your formatting flags to be non-sticky you'll need to reset it after is was used.

Comment: The problem I had is that I also want to say `std::cout << short << some_move;`. The manipulator `short` would print e.g. `e4` where `algebraic` would print `e2-e4`. So to be able to switch between formatting, I think I need to store a format flag inside the stream. OK, I'll experiment a bit with the `pword` stuff, but just to be sure: those naked `new`s in your code above, is that really exception safe?

Comment: @TemplateRex: the result of the `new` expressions are directly captured by a readily waiting `void*&` for which the clean-up was already registered. The code when changing the value isn't quite exception safe: it would cause a double `delete` if the `new` threw an exception (the fix is to use `pword = 0;` after capturing the current value and before allocating memory; I'll change that in a moment).

Comment: @TemplateRex: I'd be surprised if `std::cout << short << some_move;` would compile considering that `short` is a keyword. That said, if you just need to store a simple flag you can use `iword()` instead: it stores an `int`, i.e., you get back an `int&`. Normally I aim for using `iword()` but for the question I needed to store arbitrary strings which won't fit into an `int`.

Comment: Yes, sure, `short` was a typo, I used it because I didn't want to presume knowledge of chess notation. The actual names are `san` (standard algebraic notation, which is shortened if there are no ambiguities) and `fean` or `lan` (fully expanded or long algebraic notation). And they are indeed sticky, and on program setup I would e.g. set `std::cout` to `san`. I currently indeed use `iword`, but it feels decidely... ancient, to say the least :-)

Comment: @TemplateRex: the other approach I might consider to associate date with a stream are `std::locale`s although these are more about functionality than data and if someone `imbue()`s a new stream the information may be lost.

Comment: Re: exception safety, I was more concerned about the static `erase` with its naked `delete`. Is the string allocated by `pword` guaranteed to be cleaned up along all paths of execution, even if a non-IO related exception occurs? Or does `ostream` itself guarantee that through its destructor?

Comment: @TemplateRex: the destructor of `std::ios_base` will call the callbacks with the `erase_event`. What the code doesn't handle is using the `copyfmt_event` (when using `copyfmt()` when the string is set there will be double delete).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `std::cout`? <strike>It is buffered by default, so if it will not print anything until you put a `std::flush` or `std::endl` on it or when your program terminates.</strike>

If that doesn't work for you, I'd use a `std::stringstream` to buffer my text and just write

```
std::cout << ss.str() << std::flush;
```

when you want the actual output.

Comment: _"it will not print anything until you put a `std::flush` or `std::endl`"_ is wrong. The buffer can be flushed when full.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks for pointing that out. I guess I forgot since in many cases the buffer is large enough to hold everything, so I never experienced this situation myself.